How to properly configure a lint-staged.config.js to provide config data to lint-stage
Context: I don't have much experience working with precommit hooks. Ive got this project boilerplate in vercell boilerplate list page, but it was a bit outdated, and I had to update dependencies and make some adjustments. Then, when I tried to commit, lint-staged precommit failed. Currently I am having this error message:
  ✖ Failed to read config from file "C:/Users/NoteBoo/Desktop/BLOG/Testes/next_plus_notion/lint-staged.config.js".
✔ Preparing lint-staged...
⚠ Running tasks for staged files...
  ❯ package.json — 4 files
    ❯ *.gitignore — 1 file
      ✖ prettier --write [FAILED]
↓ Skipped because of errors from tasks.
✔ Reverting to original state because of errors...
✔ Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ prettier --write:
[error] No parser could be inferred for file "C:\Users\NoteBoo\Desktop\BLOG\Testes\next_plus_notion\.husky\.gitignore".

lint-staged.config.js file (it is placed in project root):
const escape = require('shell-quote').quote
const isWin = process.platform === 'win32'

module.exports = {
  '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md,mdx,css,html,yml,yaml,scss,sass}': filenames => {
    const escapedFileNames = filenames
      .map(filename => `"${isWin ? filename : escape([filename])}"`)
      .join(' ')
    return [
      `prettier --ignore-path='.gitignore' --write ${escapedFileNames}`,
      `git add ${escapedFileNames}`,
    ]
  },
}

package.json file:
{
  "name": "notion-blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build && node .next/server/build-rss.js",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx,md,mdx,css,html,yml,yaml,scss,sass}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.gitignore": "prettier --write"
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/react-jsx-parser": "^2.0.0",
    "async-sema": "^3.1.1",
    "github-slugger": "^2.0.0",
    "katex": "^0.16.10",
    "next": "^14.2.4",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/katex": "^0.16.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.7",
    "mrm": "2",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2"
  }
}


Original project link:
https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/notion-blog
How can I properly setup lint-staged verification so it could work with the specified lint-staged.config.js file?

Run lint-staged --debug to get a verbose output.
I came across the same problem and realized I had a typo (dot instead of comma).
